# Mathematical Proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The question gives these premises and asks how it reached the conclusion.

- ¬P ∧ R
- P ∨ Q
- ∴ Q ∨ R

Here is my approach:
premise ¬P ∧ R, we can use the Simplification rule to infer ¬P.
premise P ∨ Q, we can use the Disjunctive Syllogism rule with ¬P (from step 1) to infer Q.
premise ¬P ∧ R, we can again use the Simplification rule to infer R.
Finally, from Q (from step 2) and R (from step 3), we can use the Addition rule to infer Q ∨ R.

But I'm having doubts because ¬P is negated and I think the Simplification rule cannot be applied.

Comment: Sorry, the1st premise was supposed to be ¬P ∧ R

Comment: Doesn't matter. From premise 1: $\neg P\land R$, then $R$ (conjunction elimination), then $Q\lor R$ (disjunction introduction).

Comment: The dilemma I am having is that the conjunction elimination rule states that if a conjunction is true, then either conjunct is true. But one of the conjuncts is negated, hence one of them is false.

Comment: For $\neg P\land R$, not that "one of them is false". Both $\neg P$ is true and $R$ is true. The one that's false is $P$, which is not "one of them".

Comment: @peterwhy Thanks for answering and clarifying!